# Trying to clone a repo using git protocol leads to https error?

Tags: git

I'm trying to clone a repo over a local network using the git protocol, but am receiving the following error:

```
~/foobar$ git clone git://192.168.xxx.yyy/
Cloning into '192.168.xxx.yyy'...
fatal: unable to access 'https://192.168.xxx.yyy/': Failed to connect to 192.168.xxx.yyy port 443: Connection refused
```

A coworker was successfully able to clone using exactly the same command using a mac as a client (I'm using Ubuntu). Any idea why `git clone` seems to be trying to use https, or how to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You specify to use the git-protocol in your `git clone` command, but the error shows that git tried to use https.

This is probably an issue in your git client configuration.
If your .gitconfig contains the following remove it

```
[url "https://"]   
    insteadOf = git://
```

See: https://coderwall.com/p/sitezg/force-git-to-clone-with-https-instead-of-git-urls

Comment: Thanks, but there is no such config in my `.gitconfig`. Is there anywhere else where this could be configured?

Comment: Maybe you could look for it in `~/.config/git` or `/etc/gitconfig`

Comment: Yes, the setting was in `/etc/gitconfig`.